# Cannot insert data over Linked Server into Redshift

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, linked-server, amazon-redshift

We've setup a new linked server using the Amazon Redshift ODBC driver (x64) in SQL Server 2014 Express.  SELECT statements work as expected using OPENQUERY, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Redshift_Linked_Server, 'SELECT * FROM tableA')
```

However we cannot use the INSERT functionality of OPENQUERY, eg:

```
INSERT OPENQUERY(
    Redshift_Linked_Server, 
    'SELECT SingleValue from tableA')
VALUES ( '2' )
```

When run we get the following error message back:

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Redshift_Linked_Server" returned message "Unspecified error".
>
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Redshift_Linked_Server" returned message "Transaction cannot have multiple recordsets with this cursor type. Change the cursor type, commit the transaction, or close one of the recordsets.".
>
> Msg 7343, Level 16, State 2, Line 9
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "Redshift_Linked_Server" could not INSERT INTO table "[MSDASQL]".

This happens when inserting from a single row using VALUES or when inserting from a data set using SELECT.

Is this a driver issue or can the linked server be configured to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using EXECUTE ('INSERT INTO TABLENAME1(COL1,COL2) SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM TABBLENAME2 ') AT

Hope this is useful to someone out there.

Comment: what do you mean ? what about the openquery ?